Trying to compute unitary matrix satisfying a given property
I'm trying to find a $2\times2$ unitary matrix $V$ such that $$V^{\otimes 2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -i \\ 0 & 0 & i & 0\end{pmatrix}V^{\otimes 2}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -i\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & i & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
For context, the matrix on the LHS is the matrix representation of the quantum controlled-Pauli-Y gate with the first bit as the control. The matrix on the RHS is the matrix representation of the quantum controlled-Pauli-Y gate with the second bit as the control. In particular, I'm trying to figure out if there's a $V$ unitary so $V^{\otimes 2}$ which when applied as above swaps control from the first bit to the second bit. There doesn't seem to be a good way to do this besides brute-forcing it which seems extremely cumbersome.
From the trial matrices I've tried, it doesn't seem that such a matrix exists. And again I have no idea how to attempt this without a very ugly looking calculation.
